# Batch file for file merge

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have one folder inside that there 15 sub folder Folder1, Folder2, Folder3, etc... Each subfolder (Folder1, Folder2) has 2 or 3 level subfolders. Each folder has some .txt files. I would like to create a batch file that can 15 create merge files for each folder.

I can do it with cmd commands like `for %f in (*.txt) do type "%f" >> output.txt`.

In the above command, I need to open 15 different command prompt windows and run the above command.

Is there any way that I can achieve this programmatically like in a batch file?

Comment: Please provide some sample data (directory structure and output file)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following batch will create in all direct subfolders of `Mainfolder` a file Merge.txt containing all text files of this subfolder and below. 
It inserts a Header with full path for each text file and appends an empty line to avoid joining lines if the last line of a file doesn't end with a cr/lf.

```
@Echo off
Set "MainFolder=C:\PathTo\wherever"
For /D %%A in ("%MainFolder%\*") do (
    For /F "Delims=" %%B in ('Dir /B/S "%%A\*.txt" 2^>NUL^|Find /V "Merge.txt"') Do (
       Echo ==== %%~fB ====
       Type "%%~fB"
       Echo:
    ) "
) > "%%~fA\Merge.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is not working as Folder names have space in between that.

Comment: A pair of qoutes around `Type "%%~fB"` should have fixed that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it resolved folder name space issue. but merge file has only last text file data ...merging did not work.

Comment: Well sorry for that, minimizing parentheses the redirection got the wrong place (will now create 0 sized Merge.txt when no txt files present in that subtree)

Comment: Thanks it is working now. I did one correction:  [code] @Echo off
Set "MainFolder=C:\Users\himsoni\Desktop\FWLOGS"
For /D %%A in ("%MainFolder%\*") do (
    For /F "Delims=" %%B in ('Dir /B/S "%%A\*.txt" 2^>NUL^|Find /V "Merge.txt"') Do (
       Echo ==== %%~fB ====
       Type "%%~fB"
       Echo:
    ) 
) > "%%~fA\Merge.txt"
pause[code]

Comment: I am so sorry but one more ask. this Batch file not able to resolve network path. is there any way to set UNC path?

Comment: Try `pushd "\\server\share"`to create a temporary mapping and set "Mainfolder=."